# VisualSVN Server displays SIDs instead of human-readable domain user names

Tags: active-directory, visualsvn-server

I'm running VisualSVN Server on a machine which is a member of a domain (it's Windows Server  2008 R2). Now I'm trying to grant myself permissions to access a repository. I right-click on Repository node, click "Properties", then "Add". Standard "Select Users or Groups" dialog pops out, but what's strange about it is that it has "DEV" as "From this location", although other non-VisualSVN Server windows have domain name as Location:

[image]
<sub>(source: [rsdn.ru](http://files.rsdn.ru/27808/selectusers.png))</sub>

After adding myself (I'm in the LDAP directory), here's what VisualSVN displays in Repository Properties:

[image: link text]
<sub>(source: [rsdn.ru](http://files.rsdn.ru/27808/props.png))</sub>

And finally, try as I might, I cannot access the repository. Event Log entry for VisualSVN Server says this:

> LookupAccountSid() failed. (OS 1332) No mapping between account names and security IDs was done.  [client 192.168.0.94]

What can I do to resolve this problem?

Comment: Have you managed to solve the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Try to disable and reenable the sid cache and restart the VisualSVN Server. See the following Microsoft KB for details:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/946358

Comment: No, this won't help.